# Extern Variable - Multiple Files

Tags: c++, extern

When I redefine an `extern` variable within another file with a different type, the VS compiler is not giving an error message. As far as I know, it should raise an error since it was globally defined as an `extern` in another file. What is the reason for this behavior?

source1.cpp

```cpp
extern int x;
```

source2.cpp

```
int x = 5;
```

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
double x = 455;
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << x; // writes 455
}
```

Comment: Variables with same name but different types are different variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). **The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation**, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.